# Can you put two matrices in display mode side by side in LyX?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, matrices

I have two matrices, and I want to render them side by side with appropriate space in between in display mode. How should it be implemented in LyX?

Comment: Just insert a matrix, add a spacing, and insert another matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No idea how things are in LyX, but here's one way to do it using LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}\quad
  B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Displaying two matrices side-by-side in LaTeX should be (is!) independent of the editor (LyX). Here's a minimal example showing how to place 2 matrices next to one another:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is text.
\[
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{array}\right] \qquad
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    e & f \\
    g & h
  \end{array}\right]
\]
This is some more text.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​
```

The space between the two matrices is specified using `\qquad` (two `\quad`s). However, you can change this. For example, you may want `\hspace{5em}` or `\qquad \qquad` (4 `\quad`s) or whatever.